# "Как в старые добрые времена..." — нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая в этом предложении:

***Как в старые добрые времена(,) разыграем Васю?***

Answer (score 1):

Обособление не требуется, оборот несет обстоятельственное значение (= так же, как и в прошлый раз) и неразрывно связан со сказуемым по смыслу. Но если автор настаивает на том, что это сравнение (похоже на то, как в прошлый раз), то как авторский знак обособление возможно.

Менять что-то в предложении тоже не вижу необходимости.

Answer (score 0):

Да. Не вижу синтаксической разницы между выражениями "как всегда" и "как в старые добрые времена". И там и здесь поставил бы запятую, основываясь на правиле:
[КАК ВСЕГДА, вводное слово](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_313)

Comment: Разница-то есть, "как в старые добрые времена" - это почсти что фразеологизм. Но здесь не это существенно. В обоих случаях обособление оборота может быть авторское, зависит главным образом от того, насколько тесна его связь со сказуемым.

Answer (score 0):

Оборот обособляется в большинстве случаев, вот только структуру предложения лучше бы поменять: Разыграем Васю, как в старые добрые времена.

Пример необособленного оборота: И хочу, чтобы все было как в старые добрые времена.

**Примеры с обособлением из Нацкорпуса:**

А еще над городом висел смог, **как в старые добрые времена**. [Олег Дивов. Молодые и сильные выживут (1998)]

Кричали «ура!» , **как в старые добрые времена**. Народ соскучился по праздникам. [Евгений Ловчев. ГиП (1997) // «Столица», 1997.05.27]

Он поволнуется, посердится немножко, а потом возьмет, **как в старые добрые времена**, топоры да вилы и пойдет ломать помещичью усадьбу... [Александра Маринина. Черный список (1995)]